# Jquery change image on rollover with fade

Tags: jquery, image, fade, rollover

I'm currently using the script below to change an image on rollover. There are many images that this effect needs to be applied to -  each image has its own rollover image. The script works for the rollover, but not for the fade.

I've read about using CSS and jquery for the fade effect: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

But it would be a real pain having to write the CSS for over 100 different images! I was just wondering if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong and how to make the script work? :)

```
$(function () {
$("img.rollover").hover(function () {
    this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on")
}, function () {
    this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off")
})
});


$("a img").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
});
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks good to me.

Comment: It would help if you could also provide a sample of your HTML (at least two if the images you want to replace and fade).

Comment: Maybe the fade hover event is happening before the replace src hover event? Why do you use 2 different css selectors? Maybe try using the same selector (e.g. "img.rollover") to assign both events? Or can you do everything in the same hover event definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing the CSS for over 100 different images, why not use a jQuery `.each` loop to add the CSS for you?

```
$("img.rollover").each(function() {
    this.css('background-image',this.src.replace("_off", "_on"));
});
```

...and then follow the single-image technique from [the page you linked to](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/).